# Partial derivative of an integral transform

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have a Lagrangian of the form $\mathcal{L}(x,f)=[s(x)-\int_a^b A(x,x')f(x')dx']g(x)$, where $a,b$ are constants, and $g(x),s(x)$ and the kernel $A(x,x')$ are given .

I am interested in computing the variational derivative $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial f}$ for use in the Euler-Lagrange equation. How do I proceed?

Comment: $s$, $A$ and $g$ are given? Is $\mathcal L$ a Lagrangian?

Comment: Partial derivative? Or variational derivative? I mean, is $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial f(y)}=1$, or $\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta f(y)}=\delta(x-y)$ (delta distribution)?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify your questions above.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Vary the action functional $$ S[f]~:=~\int_a^b\! dx ~{\cal L}.$$ The stationary condition becomes 
$$ \forall x^{\prime} \in [a,b]:~~ \int_a^b\! dx~g(x) A(x,x^{\prime})~=~0 . $$